# "UNSIGNED": syntax error: on creating table query when imported to sqlite

Tags: mysql, sqlite, phpmyadmin

I was importing my mysql table into sqlite and when I was running the create table query there, i found this error and not able to fix it.
I was wondering what is the error on this query. I was told the error is near "UNSIGNED": syntax error: CREATE TABLE `t_malayalam` (
  `id` int(8) UNSIGNED

**This is my query**

```
CREATE TABLE `t_malayalam` (
  `id` int(8) UNSIGNED ZEROFILL NOT NULL,
  `b` int(11) NOT NULL,
  `c` int(11) NOT NULL,
  `v` int(11) NOT NULL,
  `t` text CHARACTER SET utf8 COLLATE utf8_bin NOT NULL
)
```

Comment: Do you want the `id` column to serve as a unique ID? (by the way, that is not a QUERY but a COMMAND).

Comment: yes, but there is some other error on that line

Comment: And you want its value from the input table or self-generated?

Answer (score 0):

There are several problems here.  One is that `CHARACTER SET utf8` is invalid since `SET` is a keyword in SQLite3. (You probably want to get rid of `COLLATE` clause anyway, since the collation 'utf8_bin' you have chosen is invalid anyway.  See https://www.sqlite.org/datatype3.html#collation for details.)  Apart from that, you need to get rid of invalid specifications after the column types like `UNSIGNED` and `ZEROFILL`.  (Also note that types like `int(8)`, while legal, are equivalent to a simple `integer` type.)

Since in your comment you said that you wanted the `id` field to be a unique indicator of a row, you should specify it:

```
id integer primary key
```

(There is no need for `NOT NULL`; that will be automatic.)

So, I think you want something like:

```
CREATE TABLE `t_malayalam` (
  `id` INTEGER PRIMARY KEY,
  `b` INTEGER NOT NULL,
  `c` INTEGER NOT NULL,
  `v` INTEGER NOT NULL,
  `t` TEXT NOT NULL
  )
```

Note that the backticks are all unnecessary (and non-standard SQL), but don't do any harm either.